# Customize modeline to display name of prev/next buffer

Tags: buffers, mode-line

As topic says - I'm using `tabbar` + `tabbar-forward-tab` to quickly switch between recent buffers right now, but I don't really like it. I'd rather have the names of the previous and next buffer show up in my modeline, and use the built in buffer switch functions instead. Sounds easy, but I couldn't find where the buffer names are stored. Also, I don't know if modifying the modeline is trivial either.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can certainly do this, but your problem is that the code used by `switch-to-next-buffer` and `switch-to-previous-buffer` for deciding which buffer to switch to is somewhat complex, and not isolated from the actual "switch-to" behaviour; so (a) you would need to replicate quite a lot of code; and (b) the mode line is updated *really* frequently, so doing a lot of processing on each refresh is not ideal.

Comment: Buffers are stored in
the
[`buffer-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-List.html).
I don't think you can quite do what you want to do, however.  It
stores buffers in order of recent use, so the "previous" and the
"next" buffer are the same thing.  Aside from that, putting the
name of the next/previous buffer in the modeline would probably be
more confusing than it's worth: I imagine it would be easy to
forget that you're editing the *current* buffer, *not* the buffer
listed in the modeline.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but just thought I'd mention it. If you put your mouse (if you have one) pointer over the buffer name in the mode line you'll see that it tells you that clicking `mouse-1` takes you to the previous buffer and clicking `mouse-3` takes you to the next buffer.